# Reading RC switch input from i-bus using arduino

Tags: arduino, rc

I am using an Arduino Due to read i-bus data from a Flysky receiver. I am using the code from https://gitlab.com/timwilkinson/FlySkyIBus to read the data.

Reading data from all channels is very straight forward, except for any switch input. I can't find a method to read the switch data. I used the example code and read all the channels.

```
#include "FlySkyIBus.h"
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  IBus.begin(Serial1);

}

void loop() 
{
  IBus.loop();
  Serial.print(IBus.readChannel(0), HEX);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(IBus.readChannel(1), HEX);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(IBus.readChannel(2), HEX);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(IBus.readChannel(3), HEX);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(IBus.readChannel(4), HEX);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(IBus.readChannel(5), HEX);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(IBus.readChannel(6), HEX);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(IBus.readChannel(7), HEX);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(IBus.readChannel(8), HEX);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.println(IBus.readChannel(9), HEX);

}
```

Does anyone know any way read the switch data?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have figured out the solution.
The transmitter needs to be set up such that it can transmit the switch data as a channel. Once that is done IBus.readChannel will be able to read the values.